# How can I use a canvas image in a function that, first manipulates then outputs the newly manipulated image back to user

Tags: javascript, canvas, onclick, listener

So far I have a button that when clicked outputs the canvas image in a pop-up window using the toDataURL() method, allowing the image to be saved as a .png.  I also have a button, that when clicked will take the original user-generated canvas image and display it in on second canvas.  Both of these were implemented in my effort to:  take the original canvas image and use that image in a function that manipulates the image and recursively calls the image, outputting the manipulated image back to the user. Im new to js but I have knowledge with OO lang's- If I could use Java I would do this:

```
public CanvasImage manipulator(userImage){
    do this to image;
    do this to image;
    return manipulatedImage; //this needs to be a save-able image (toDataURL i think)
}
```

What do I need to do to get this functionality captured with an onClick event using javaScript? Im Stuck, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about doing per-pixel manipulation on the image you need to use `.getImageData(x, y, width, height)`, this gives you and object that contains the `.data` field which is an array of every pixel's RGBA of the image, so `.data[0]` is the first pixel's R channel, `.data[1]` is the G channel, `.data[2]` the B, `.data[3]` the Alpha channel, and then `.data[4]` is the R channel of the second pixel.

All in 0-255 range, not 0-1.

You can set these color values, maybe you want your first pixel to be blue, then you do it:

```
var img = Ctx.getImageData(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
img.data[0] = 0; // R
img.data[1] = 0; // G
img.data[2] = 255; // B
img.data[3] = 255; // A
```

To draw your modified image data, just use `Ctx.putImageData(img, x, y)`;

Your onclick event would look like this:

```
button.Canvas = Canvas;
button.Ctx = CanvasContext;
button.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var img = this.Ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.Canvas.width, this.Canvas.height);
    // Do something to the image data here
    this.Ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

**Or**

You may just want to draw your image to an off-screen canvas, do whatever you want there and then draw it back to the canvas that the user can see. Since you said you're new to JS, this is how you create your canvas:

```
var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var newCtx = Canvas.getContext("2d");
```

this canvas will not be displayed if you don't want to, so just use it normaly and when you're done manipulating your image just draw it on the main canvas.